# Microsoft Access VBA Populating a field of a percentage of total records

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

When I click on button `command9` I want to use the count function to count how many records matching `combo7` and `Insp_Cat = 1`, then calculate 20% of the total records. Then using the `Update` statement update the field `Insp_Type` to "C" ,limiting the number of records to 20% of total records previously calculated.

This is the code I have to date but getting a syntax error on the count line.

```vb
Private Sub Command9_Click()
Dim strSql As String
Dim Rec_Qty As Integer
Dim Rec_Perc As Integer
'Return record count for all records in Tbl_Inspections matching WO_ID in Combo7 and Insp_Cat =1

Rec_Qty = Count (WO_ID & Insp_Cat) Where [WO_ID]= Me.[Combo7]& [Insp_Cat]=1 From Tbl_Inspections

Rec_Per = Rec_Qty * 0.2

'Update records for "C" 20% records using Rec_Per value in limit function of Update command
strSql = "Update Tbl_Inspections"
strSql = strSql & "Set Insp_Type = 'C' WHERE WO_ID = Me.Combo7 & Insp_Cat = 1 & Limit = Rec_Per"
CurrentDb.Execute strSql
End Sub
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is the *Rec_Qty* line pseudo code? As is, it is not compliant in VBA. Also, you need a space before the `Set` in update query.

Answer (score 0):

Can't use Count() function in VBA, only within a query or in textbox on form or report.

DCount() and other domain aggregate functions used in VBA.

Concatenate literal text and variables.

`Rec_Qty = DCount("*", "Tbl_Inspections", "[WO_ID]= " & Me.[Combo7] & " AND [Insp_Cat]=1")`

`CurrentDb.Execute "Update Tbl_Inspections Set Insp_Type = 'C' WHERE WO_ID = " & Me.Combo7 & " AND Insp_Cat = 1 AND Limit = " & Rec_Per`